# What does the keyword this reference in this code sample?

Tags: java, android

```
public class NewPlanet extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    ImageView marsImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageMars);
    marsImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WorldGen mars = new WorldGen("Mars", 642, 3.7);
            mars.setPlanetColonies(1);
            Toast.makeText(NewPlanet.this, "Mars Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

What context does `NewPlanet.this` reference? Why does `makeText` from class `Toast` need this context? I understand the use of keyword `this` when referencing a class and using dot notation to access its fields and constructors as in `this.field`, but what about when the `this` keyword comes after a class reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance `NewPlanet.this` represent object of `NewPlanet` that is an outer class. If you have used only `this`, it would represent the instance of anonymous class `OnClickListener`.

After compilation you will get something like this:

`marsImage.setOnClickListener$1(new OnClickListener$1(this));`

```
 static class OnClickListener$1 implements OnClickListener {
        private final NewPlanet ref;
        OnClickListener$1(NewPlanet ref) {
           this.ref= ref;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WorldGen mars = new WorldGen("Mars", 642, 3.7);
            mars.setPlanetColonies(1);
            Toast.makeText(ref, "Mars Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it's a reference to the enclosing outer class instance, and not a reference to the NewPlanet class?

Comment: Yes. If you would like to access the reference to its class you could do `NewPlanet.this.getClass()`.

Answer (score 2):

`NewPlanet.this` is a reference to `this` of outer class. Indeed you are using this from anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to the NewPlanet that the onCreate() method is called on